# What is the effect of `const_cast`, when the change of "const-ness" is not required?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, const-cast, well-formed

A `const_cast` is used either to remove or to add the "const-ness" of an object.
However, what is the effect or behaviour of such cast, which doesn't change the "const-ness"?

In other words, what happens if `const_cast<Class&>(object)` is applied on an `object` which is already of non-const `Class` type.
Similarly, what happens if `const_cast<const Class&>(object)` is applied on an `object`, which is already of `const Class` type.

Though I feel that it should be well defined, but still wanted to confirm it. Especially if there is any authoritative reference or something in standards.

**Use case**: In the templated code, sometime to avoid extra code we may want to `const_cast` every object coming its way. It can be passed with `const` or non-`const` objects. e.g.

```
struct X {
  void foo ();
};

template<typename T>
void call_foo (T& t)  // `T` is either `X` or `const X` (& possibly children of `X`)
{
  X& x = const_cast<X&>(t);
  x.foo();
}
```

<sub>Assume that, for time being we are not worried about `volatile` specifier.</sub>

Comment: Might be an issue if `object` was volatile?

Comment: You can use `static_cast` to add const-ness, but only `const_cast` can remove it.

Comment: A key property of a non-`const` reference to an object is that it can be used to change the referenced object.   If that object is already not `const`, it can already be changed. So obtaining a non-`const` reference to it - by any means - changes nothing.

Comment: `const_cast` changes the `const`-ness of an expression. It is not possible to change the const-ness of an object.

Comment: "In the templated code, we may not know if the passed object is of type const or not" - actually you do always know

Comment: @M.M, yes technically we always know the "const-ness". But sometimes, we want to resort on simple casting instead of going with the `template` SFINAE & rewriting the code. Analogically it's like `<typename T> void foo (T t) { x = (int)(t); };` Here we expect `T` to be convertible to `int`. However instead of writing various overloads of `foo`, we may choose to simply typecast it.

Comment: @iammilind disagree . If you have a specific piece of code in mind for this use then post a question about it.  It's extremely rare to have a valid use for `const_cast` other than to access a non-const-correct API

Answer (score 4):

It's perfectly fine.  There will be no effect--as if you didn't have the `const_cast` at all.

Do note that you can use [`std::is_const`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_const) to check if a particular type is const.  But if the only reason to do it would be to avoid a no-op `const_cast`, I wouldn't bother.

Comment: Is there any standard reference on this part?

Comment: @iammilind: On what, the fact that `int x; const_cast<int&>(x)` gives you an `int&`?

Comment: A reference from the standard which says that `const_cast` will result in no-op or no-effect, if the "const"-ness of the object or type is same. Personally I feel that the standard may not put such trivial cases, however the main purpose for this Qn was to get some authoritative reference.

Comment: @iammilind: If you want authoritative references, I suggest adding the "language lawyer" tag.  (I would remove the "casting" tag - and probably "const" too.)

Answer (score 1):

If an object is not `const`, using `const_cast<>` to remove `const`ness makes no difference.   Removing an attribute from something which already lacks that attribute, logically, does nothing.

An exception is if the object is also volatile, for example;

```
 volatile SomeType x;   // const qualifier may also be used here

 SomeType &something = const_cast<SomeType &>(x);
```

which also removes the `volatile` qualifier, whether `x` is `const` or not.    Any use of something to access `x` then causes undefined behaviour.

If this example is changed to something like

```
 SomeType y;
 volatile SomeType& x(y);
 SomeType &something = const_cast<SomeType &>(x);
```

then using `something` is legal (since `y` is not volatile), but if `x` is used to modify `y` in some way, the compiler may or may not ensure those changes are reflected when `something` is accessed (or vice versa).   This would make it quite challenging to verify that the code works as intended if (say) a signal handler does something to `x`.

For your use case, there is no point in using `const_cast`.   It is easy enough to overload a function so it takes a `const` or non-`const` reference.

```
  void func(Something &x);
  void func(const Something &x);
```

where the second will be called if given a `const` object.    Using `const_cast` to remove `const`ness has no effect in the first.  In the second, it potentially permits changing something that is not changeable, so may result in undefined behaviour (if the non`const` reference is used in that way).

Comment: The standard does say that `1 + 1 == 2` (via the definitions of the operators and literals involved)

Comment: In your first example , using `something` to access `x` will cause undefined behaviour (volatile object may not be accessed by non-volatile expression)

Comment: Make the example be `SomeType y; volatile SomeType& x(y); SomeType &something = const_cast<SomeType &>(x);` and the example becomes legal.

Comment: Yeah, okay.   Updated.